# Fragments are not showing inside tablayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I'm populating `TabLayout` with fragments without `ViewPager`. But when selected a tab my fragments are not displaying inside tab. If I'm making it below toolbar its text is diplayed below toolbar and at the top of tabs, but it never shows inside tab. Here is the XML.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/toolbarColor"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And the `MainActivity` is here.

```
switch(tab.getPosition()){
    case 0:
        Log.i("MainActivity ", "one ");
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame, new TodayFragment());

        break;

    case 1:
        FragmentManager fm1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ft = fm1.beginTransaction();
        Log.i("MainActivity ", "two");
        ft.replace(R.id.frame, new SettingsFragment());
}

ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Each `Fragment` has a single `TextView`.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Note that this **does not** mean to post your entire app.

Comment: Can you please the screenshots of App, like how it is displaying your screens.

Comment: Its just two blank tabs and when tab is selected nothing happens it remains blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as you didn't provide your full xml, I think the `Toolbar`, `TabLayout` and the `FrameLayout` are inside a `RelativeLayout`.

Now as far as I can understand you could load the `Fragment`s correctly, but they are not showing as they are hidden under some other layout. So to get rid of your problem you need to make the layout design like this.

```
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/toolbarColor"
        android:elevation="3dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"/>
<RelativeLayout/>
```

Just get rid of `FrameLayout` and use a `RelativeLayout` as your fragment container and put it under your `TabLayout` to see if its working now.

Comment: Could fragments dynamically change inside relative layout, and yes root layout is relative layout

Comment: Why not. You can have a `LinearLayout` too as your fragments holder. Its upto you actually. But as I suggested, simpler is better.

Comment: Yes sort of, please see my other question

Comment: Where's your other question?

Answer (score 0):

The root layout should be linear layout don't understand why it must be  linear layout but it the way it is